# Skienna's recursive algorithm for edit distance

Tags: algorithms, edit-distance

I'm having some trouble understanding part of Skienna's algorithm for edit distance presented in his Algorithm Design Manual. I'm posting the recursive version, prior to when he applies dynamic programming to the problem, but my question still stands in that version too I think.

He provides the following code:

```
#define MATCH       0
#define INSERT      1
#define DELETE      2

int match(char c, char d)
{
    if (c == d) return(0);
    else return(1);
}

int indel(char c)
{
    return(1);
}

int string_compare(char *s, char *t, int i, int j)
{
        int k;                  /* counter */
        int opt[3];             /* cost of the three options */
        int lowest_cost;        /* lowest cost */

        if (i == 0) return(j * indel(' '));
        if (j == 0) return(i * indel(' '));

        opt[MATCH] = string_compare(s,t,i-1,j-1) + match(s[i],t[j]);
        opt[INSERT] = string_compare(s,t,i,j-1) + indel(t[j]);
        opt[DELETE] = string_compare(s,t,i-1,j) + indel(s[i]);

        lowest_cost = opt[MATCH];
        for (k=INSERT; k<=DELETE; k++)
                if (opt[k] < lowest_cost) lowest_cost = opt[k];

        return( lowest_cost );
}
```

I am having trouble understanding the logic behind how the indices are decremented when arriving at opt[INSERT] and opt[DELETE]. They seem backwards to me.

How can I prove to myself that they are correct?

Comment: The code fragment you've posted doesn't make sense on its own. None of `MATCH`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `match()`, `indel()` is defined, for example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks for the head's up-- the missing code is added.

Comment: Do you understand the underlying recurrence relation, as seen e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance#Basic_algorithm)? See also [this similar question here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/28734/98). (duplicate?)

Comment: @Raphael It's the intuition on the recurrence relationship that I'm missing. How can I gain the intuition that the way the indices are decremented in the recursive calls to string_compare are correct?

Comment: Not shooting the messenger but, ugh. It turns out that `indel()` and `match()` are both ridiculous: the first is just an inefficient way of writing `1` and the second is called "match" but returns false if its arguments match and true if they don't.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think that the 3 lines of code at the end, including an array, a for loop and a conditional to compute the smallest of three integers is a real achievement. This said, I hate reading code.

Comment: @Chris In that case, you should drop all the code, post the recurrence instead and phrase your question in its terms.

Comment: If your intuition is missing: look at it as a matrix that gets floodfilled with distances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two strings `s` and `t` are compared starting from the high index,
down to index `1`. This is not visible since the initial call to
`string_compare` is not provided. The `i` and `j` arguments for that
initial call are the length of strings `s` and `t`.

It should be noted that `s` and `t` could be globals, since they are
the same in all calls.

A call to the function `string_compare(s,t,i,j)` is intended to
compute the minimum edit distance of the prefixes `s[1..i]` and `t[1..j]`.
It first compares the two strings at indices `i` and `j`, and the
recursively at lower indices.

It always tries 3 ways of finding the shortest distance:

1. by assuming there was a match or a susbstitution edit depending on
   whether `s[i]==t[j]`;
2. by assuming there is an insertion edit of `t[j]`;
3. by assuming there is an deletion edit of `s[i]`;

Then it computes recursively the sortest distance for the rest of both
strings, and adds 1 to that result, when there is an edit on this call.

When `s[i]==t[j]` the two strings match on these indices. Hence the
corresponding indices are both decremented, to recursively compute the
shortest distance of the prefixes `s[1..i-1]` and `t[1..j-1]`. A
proper match does not increase the distance. Hence
dist(`s[1..i]`,`t[1..j]`)= dist(`s[1..i-1]`, `t[1..j-1]`).

When `s[i]=/=t[j]` the two strings do not match, but can be made to
match by a substitution edit. Hence the same recursive call is
possible, but the resulting shortest distance must be incremented by
one for the substitution edit. Hence dist(`s[1..i]`,`t[1..j]`)=
dist(`s[1..i-1]`, `t[1..j-1]`)+1.

That is why the function match returns `0` when there is a match, and
`1` when there is none.

Another possibility is not to try for a match, but assume that `t[j]`
is due to an insertion edit in the case of the smallest distance.
Hence that inserted symbol is ignored by replacing `t[1..j]` by
`t[1..j-1]`, ie by computing the shortest distance of `s[1..i]` and
`t[1..j-1]`, which is `string_compare(s,t,i,j-1)`, and then adding `1`
for the insertion edit.

The next and last try is the symmetric one, when one assume that the
symbol `s[i]` was deleted, and thus does not have to appear in `t`.

The results of the 3 attempts are strored in the array `opt`, and the
smallest value of the 3 is kept as shortest distance for `s[1..i]` and
`t[1..j]`.

The decrementations of indices is either because the corresponding
string elements match, or because they have been taken into account by
an edit operation.

Comment: That is helpful although I still feel that my understanding is shakey. Do you know of any good resources to accelerate feeling comfortable with problems like this? Or is it instead just a matter of putting in the time studying?

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is. Is it this specific problem,
before even using dynamic programming. I do not know where there would
be any resource to help that, other than working on it or asking more
specific questions. The basic idea here is jsut to find the best
editing strategy (with smallest number of edits) by exploring all
possible editing strategies and computing the cost of each, keeping
only the smaller cost. It is simply expressed as a recursive
exploration. Regarding dynamic programming, you will find many
testbooks on algorithmics.